# KML from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:900913

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, kml, coordinate-system

I'm trying to create KML files manually (XML format) by extracting data from a postGIS database with "geography" values in a column.

But i believe i need to transform the projection of each row in the database from EPSG:4326 to EPSG: 900913.. How can i do that?

Code:

```
 map = new OpenLayers.Map({
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
numZoomLevels:16,
zoom: 0,
maxResolution:156543.0339,
units:'m',
projection: "EPSG:900913",
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
div: "map_canvas",
controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        ],
});


var KML = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "assets/text.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: false, 
                extractAttributes: true

            })
        })
    });
```

- Coordinate system in database: (one "Area") / Polygon.

> -179.999995473772 -89.9999977368861,-89.9999954737723 -89.9999977368861,4.52622771263123e-    06 -89.9999977368861,90.0000045262277 -89.9999977368861,179.999995473772     -89.9999977368861,179.999995473772 89.9999977368861,90.0000045262277     89.9999977368861,4.52622771263123e-06 89.9999977368861,-89.9999954737723     89.9999977368861,-179.999995473772 89.9999977368861,-179.999995473772 -89.9999977368861

Current error:

> Uncaught Bad LineString point coordinates: -179.999995473772

Comment: why dont u use ST_GeomFromKML?

Comment: its probably the other way around.. From database to a KML file.. not from a KML into database..

Comment: The result from 1 column as you can see in my post is a "as_kml" result.

Comment: You might run into problems if your data exceeds 85.0511 to the North and South. North and South pole are not allowed in projection 900913.

Comment: Good to know @AndreJoost, But how can i transform these coordinates to that coordinate system ?

Comment: I would move the points manually in Qgis, or try a geometry within populated area first. By the way: should the value of -179.9999 be lat or long?

Comment: 900913 is out of date, go for 3857 or 3395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a way to do it:

```
´format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2,
                'internalProjection': options.projections.source, //EPSG:3785/900913
                'externalProjection': options.projections.display //EPSG:4326
            })´
```

Hope this helps anyone else :)

Comment: How do you get the options object?

Comment: Hi Alexis_A, this post is 4 years old, but if i remember correcly, options is just a custom object, (the one you use when intiializing Map(). (see original question) - It seems like you can use .GetOptions() as well to get the current options. (http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the map center from a given pair of lat/lon coordinates, I use the following in Openlayers:

```
               var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
```

Maybe this function can help you with KML.